# Не работают флэш баннеры в мозиле

Tags: flash, firefox, html, css

Не работают флэш баннеры в мозиле, а в других браузерах - все нормально. Кто сталкивался и решал этот вопрос, подскажите? Установлен флэш плеер последний. настройки не трогал, не работает и у друзей, других плагинов нету.

Comment: Вообще не работают или вы над каким то своим проектом работаете?

Comment: некоторые флэшки не работают, буду искать в чем трабл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

? ничего не понятно. какие баннеры?
поиграем в угадайку:

1. не стоит флеш плеер для огнелиса
2. отключен яваскрипт
3. стоят какие-то плагины, которые блокируют флеш
4. стоят плагины, которые по каким-то критериям блокируют ссылки откуда грузится флеш
5. вспышки на солнце
6. очередной метеорит, проелтая недалеко от солнечной системы воздействует на магнитное поле земли, которые в свою очередь воздействует на ваш компьютер, который спасаясь от разрушения перенаправляет волны четко в фаерфокс, вырезая тем самым весь флеш из страницы.

Поставте задачу правильно, лучше с примерами, спросите у друзей загружается ли у них ваш флеш в фаерфоксе.